# Python home directory in Windows / Problem with multiple versions

Tags: python, windows, collabnet

I'm using Python 3 for developing and CollabNet Subversion Edge as versioning software. Subversion Edge comes with a little program called ViewVC which is written in Python 2, which is also directly bundled with it. There is a system environment variable called PYTHONHOME.

- If it is set to the Python 2 distribution from Subversion Edge, my Python 3 won't start (not even IDLE), instead giving a runtime error messagebox.
- If it is set to Python 3, ViewVC doesn't work.

Is there a way to make both work at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to set PYTHONHOME at all. Python uses it (if set) to locate its installation. Typically, it should be able to locate it without this variable, as well: by looking at the path name of the python executable, and, failing that, by looking into the registry.

Comment: what do you mean with "path name of the python executable"? .. and indeed you're right, both work perfectly when I just rename the variable! Well then, what's it for... Thanks!

Comment: When Python is run, you typically invoke python.exe. This is located somewhere on disk (twice: once for 2.x, and once for 3.x). Depending on which one is launched, Python figures out where its installation is.

Answer (score 0):

Write a .bat or cmd file that saves the value of the PYTHONHOME env var, invokes ViewVC and wait for it to finish, then restores PYTHONHOME to the saved value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing the Subversion Edge services to run as a specific user account, and then move the PYTHONHOME environment variable to a user-level variable for that account only?  As opposed to a system-wide variable?  It seems like it should work.

BTW, the PYTHONHOME variable is added for mod_python to work properly (which is what serves ViewVC).  If you can find another way to get mod_python to work, then you could try that.

Comment: hi, thanks for your additional comment. I've heard of this practice for services in general, but haven't considered it here. Might be worth a try. As for ViewVC, I have renamed the env variable to edit_PYTHONHOME_edit and now both things work. So you are probably wrong there (I have yet to try it after a reboot, though.)